# How pressing the enter key automatically in the shell script?

Tags: shell, installation

I have trying to make auto install shell script for Sun java web server.
But, from the start, have some trouble.

when I start up the setup manually, I need to press enter key several times to agree licenses.

but I don't know how to replace the enter key automatically on the shell script.

could you someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` and pipes. Something like:

```
(echo; echo; echo) | my_setup
```